# How can I remove these "lines" in github readme profile

Tags: github, line, visible

In my own profile readme github profile I see this ugly lines. Not sure how can I fix it.

Can someone help me that? Need to change the icons?
You can check the code below which I use for the icons.

```
<!-- Languages  -->
<h3 align="left">Languages I code with:</h3>
<p align="left"> 
  <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devicons/devicon/master/icons/javascript/javascript-original.svg" alt="javascript" width="50" height="50"/>
</a> 
  <a href="https://reactjs.org/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devicons/devicon/master/icons/react/react-original-wordmark.svg" alt="react" width="50" height="50"/>
</a>
```

[image]

Comment: you can try this
https://github.com/tandpfun/skill-icons/blob/main/readme.md